# infor/connection return false even device has internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As the title, I am using `infor/connection` to check the connection from client to database but if I uninstall and reinstall app, the `infor/connection` return `true` and return `false` after that, even if the device can access the internet, I have tested on real and virtual device and this issue still remains.

this is the code for checking connect tion:

```
 mValueEventConnection = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                boolean isConnected = dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);

                updateConnectionStatus(isConnected);

                Log.d("SSSSS-CONNECTION", isConnected + "");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("SSSSS-CONNECTION", databaseError + "");
            }
        };

        CONNECT_REF.addValueEventListener(mValueEventConnection);
```

and the result:

```
 D/SSSSS-CONNECTION: true
 D/SSSSS-CONNECTION: false
```

UPDATE:

After reinstall and open app the first time, the issue will occur, but the second time does not.

Comment: The `.info/connection` pseudo-node indicates whether the client has a connection to the Firebase Database server, which is more than just having a connection to the internet. Note that the Firebase client automatically connects after a minute, if there is no active data listener and there are no writes.

Comment: so, quick question. How can I make it return true in this case. should I read or write something to database ?

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "disconnects" there, but I think you understood me correctly. To keep the connection open, ensure there is an active listener. So attach a listener to some regular part of your data. It doesn't even matter if the data exists, so `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ThisDoesNotExist").addValueEventListener(...)`.

Comment: thanks Frank, I use ```keepsynced``` to keep an empty listener on database and it's fine now

Comment: Cool. Thanks for confirming. I'll add an answer in that case, as the lack of listeners/writes is what explained the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.info/connection` pseudo-node indicates whether the client has a connection to the Firebase Database server, which is more than just having a connection to the internet.

Note that the Firebase client automatically disconnects after a minute, if there is no active data listener and there are no writes. So if you have no active listeners or writes, and the disconnect happens about a minute or so after the connect, that could explain the behavior.

In that last case you can attach a listener to some regular part of your data, or some non-existing node: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ThisDoesNotExist").addValueEventListener(...)`.